# Attempt to read property "alamat" on null - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

hello I have 2 databases, namely users and profiles, profiles has a foreign key that is user_id. Then the relationship between the two is one to one.

**Users migration**

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

**Profiles migration**

```
Schema::create('profiles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('alamat')->nullable();
        $table->string('nip')->nullable();
        $table->string('jabatan')->nullable();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

**User Model**

```
use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;

protected $fillable = [
    'name',
    'email',
    'password',
];

protected $hidden = [
    'password',
    'remember_token',
];

protected $casts = [
    'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
];

public function profile()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Profile::class, 'user_id');
}
```

**Profile Model**

```
use HasFactory;


protected $table = 'profiles';

protected $guarded = [];

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
}
```

**Profile Controller**

```
public function render()
{
    $userProfile = Profile::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->first();
    if (!$userProfile) {
        $profile = new Profile();
        $profile->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
        $profile->save();
    }
    $user = User::find(Auth::user()->id);
    return view('profile.index', ['user' => $user]);
}
```

**Profile index.blade.php**

```
<x-app-layout>
<x-slot name="header">
    <h2 class="font-semibold text-xl text-gray-800 leading-tight">
        {{ __('Dashboard') }}
    </h2>
</x-slot>

<div class="py-12">
    <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
        <div class="bg-white overflow-hidden shadow-sm sm:rounded-lg">
            <div class="p-6 bg-white border-b border-gray-200">
                Your Profile!
                <div>
                    <p>Nama :{{ $user->name }}</p>
                    <p>Email : {{ $user->email }}</p>
                    <p>Alamat : {{ $user->profile->alamat }}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

the code above produces an error that is Attempt to read property "address" on null. so how do i solve it?

Answer (score 0):

On your render method, you can do something like this:

```
 if(!\Auth::check()){
   abort(401);
 }
 $user = \Auth::user();
 $user->load('profile');
 return view('profile.index', ['user' => $user]);
```

The above code is just the optimization with eager loading. This should give you the profile address:

```
$user->profile->alamat
```

Three things you have to confirm while doing this:

- Is the user authenticated? If the user is not logged in you might not get data.
- Is the route wrap in `auth` or similar middleware? If not, you might not get `auth` data.
- Is there data in `profiles` table of the current user currently logged in?